# How to change place of children widgets in Column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to change the place of the widget in my UI. But I could not achieve it.

I tried this code But it does not work for me. If someone knows how to do it please help.

Change Place of BankCard Widget to Another BankCard Widget, or change the place of any widgets in a `Column`.

Below you can find code that I tried:

```
Widget nonNullBody(List<GetConversionCards> cards) {
    _column=Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Text(
          "fromSum".tr(),
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: BankCard(
              card: Bank.CreditCardModel.fromUzCard(
                  cards[bloc.selectedIndex.value])),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.sync),
          onPressed: () {


            _key.currentState.setState(() {
              Widget t=_column.children[0];
              _column.children[0]=_column.children[3];
              _column.children[3]=t;
            });
          },
        ),
        Text("toVisa".tr(),
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: BankCard(
              card: Bank.CreditCardModel.fromVisaCard(
                  cards[bloc.selectedIndex.value])),
        ),
      ],);
    bloc.tokenCardUzs = cards[0].uzsCardId;
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: size.height - appBar().preferredSize.height + 5,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 30,
                child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: bloc.selectedIndex,
                    builder: (context, v, w) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: cards.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              width: 8.0,
                              height: 8.0,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: bloc.selectedIndex.value == index
                                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
                            );
                          });
                    }),
              ),
              Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                flex: 5,
                child: PageView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: cards.length,
                    onPageChanged: (_) {
                      bloc.tokenCardUzs = cards[_].uzsCardId;
                      bloc.selectedIndex.value = _;
                    },
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return StatefulBuilder(
                        key: _key,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            void Function(void Function()) state) {
                          return _column; );
                    }),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: TextFieldWidget(
                  controller: bloc.amountFieldController,
                  iconData: Icons.monetization_on,
                  validator: null,
                  hintText: "enterAmount".tr(),
                  labelText: "dollarCurrency".tr(),
                ),
              ),
              ConfirmButton(
                text: 'next'.tr(),
                onPressed: () {
                  showPopUp(context, () async {
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                    waitTransactionWidget(context);

                    int usd =
                        (double.parse(bloc.amountFieldController.text) * 100)
                            .toInt();
                    bool result = await Repository.getInstance()
                        .convUzsUsd(bloc.tokenCardUzs, usd);
                    print("result conv $result");
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        PageTransition(
                            child: MyHomePage(),
                            type: PageTransitionType.fade));
                  },
                      title: Text("wouldYouLikeToExchange".tr()),
                      subtitle: Text("${bloc.amountFieldController.text} " +
                          "dollarCurrency".tr()));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you create a list that contains widgets then assign it to the childrens parameters of Column. So when you change something about the list it will change the column as well.

like this :

```
  List<Widget> list = new List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Column(
      children: list,
    );
  }

  adjustWidgetList() {
    setState(() {
      list.add(Text("lorem ipsum"));
      list.add(Text("dolar sit amet."));
            .
            .
            .
      list.remove(0);
    });

  }
```

But don't forget to make your changes inside of setState.